# JDownloader: "Invalid download directory" error

Tags: raspbian, hard-drive, usb-power, permissions

I've just set up *JDownloader* on my *Raspberry Pi 2* and I'm getting an annoying error:

> *Invalid download directory.*

I have to mention that I've attached a 500GB external hard drive to the raspberry and set the app to download the files to the hdd.

What's wrong with this app? Is it a problem with the usb connection? Lack of power? Lack of permissions to write to the hdd?

Please help!

*(I'm dummy and new to the linux and raspberry world!)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured it out and that seemed to be a problem with the usb current.

Thanks to [this topic](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=49289&sid=94e86789bab742a2ca06662eca9149fd&start=25), I added two lines of code to the file located at "*/boot/config.txt*" and set the maximum usb current to 1 amp.

The code:

```
safe_mode_gpio=4
max_usb_current=1
```

It has already solved the problem and the app is working seamlessly.